# Алгоритм блочного симметричного шифрования

Tags: visual-c++, алгоритм, c++, шифрование

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

unsigned char encryptCBC( unsigned char* buffer, int size, unsigned char key,        unsigned char CBC ) {
// <ToDo> : implement encryption algorithm
return CBC;
}

     unsigned char decryptCBC( unsigned char* buffer, int size, unsigned char key,    unsigned char CBC ) {
// <ToDo> : implement decryption algorithm
return CBC;
 }

 int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
enum CipherMode { ENCRYPT, DECRYPT };
if( argc != 5 ) {
    cerr << "Bad input parameters" << endl;
    return -1;
}
unsigned char key = atoi( argv[ 1 ] );
int mode = ENCRYPT;
if( strcmpi( argv[ 2 ], "dec" ) ) {
    mode = DECRYPT;
}

char *inputFName = argv[ 3 ];
char *outputFName = argv[ 4 ];

FILE *input, *output;
input = fopen( inputFName, "rb" );
output = fopen( outputFName, "wb" );

if( input && output ) {
    int totalCount = 0;
    unsigned char buffer[ BUFFER_SIZE ];
    unsigned char CBC = 0;
    while( !feof( input) ) {
        int actuallyRead = fread( ( void* )buffer, sizeof( buffer[ 0 ] ), BUFFER_SIZE, input );
        if( mode == ENCRYPT ) {
            CBC = encryptCBC( buffer, actuallyRead, key, CBC );
        } else {
            CBC = decryptCBC( buffer, actuallyRead, key, CBC );
        }
        fwrite( ( void* )buffer, sizeof( buffer[ 0 ] ), actuallyRead, output );
        totalCount += actuallyRead;
    }
    cout << totalCount << " bytes processed" << endl;
} else {
    cerr << "Can't open input or output file" << endl;
}
fclose( input );
fclose( output );
cin.get();

}
```

Кто знает блочный алгоритм шифрования? Там нужно по исключающему или накладывать шифр-блок на ключ, а как это написать не знаю... Там 2 функции.

Comment: > unsigned char encryptCBC( unsigned char* buffer, int size, unsigned char key, unsigned char CBC )

Тут явная проблема с типами. Ключ и вектор инициализации (кстати, зачем он обозван «CBC»?) явно не один символ.

Comment: Это режим сцепления блоков. Размер ключа взят 8 бит, поэтому и инициализация в 1символ

Comment: В качестве блочного алгоритма можете посмотреть [напимер, TEA](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TEA) , там образцы encrypt()/decrypt() есть и куча ссылок на разную литературу.

Только файл придется читать и передавать чуть по другому, частями кратными размеру шифроблока.

Answer (score 1):

Ай, моя любимая тема... Тебе сначала гамму нужно, в размер кодируемой информации. Если можешь перевести с js, то вот вариант:

```
<код удалён по причине несоответствия тематике вопроса>
```

А потом каждый байт исходной информации xor'ить каждым байтом гаммы. Соостетственно для decode - наоборот. Думаю разберёшься. XOR - не такое уж и сложное шифрование.

Comment: нет,тут что-то совсем не из той степи)смотрите внимательнее код, там 2 функции, одна шифрования, другая расшифрования, из bat файла который вызывает скрипт извлекаются параметры, -ключ, текстовый файл зашифрованной информации, текстовый файл расшифрованной информации, и нужно всего лишь несколько строк в каждую функцию дописать

Comment: ok, завтра разберусь. Сегодня уже батарейка села.

Comment: Там входной файл с информацией и выходной файл в виде результата работы программы. Вам нужно побайтно перебрать входной буфер (если не поддерживается построчный xor), с каждым байтом которого произвести операцию xor (buffer^gamma). Вот про эту гамму я и говорил. Гамма нужна для того, чтобы шифрование получилось более шифрованым, сгенерировать её можно из password, довести до размера буфера. Соответственно для расшифровки - всё наоборот, за исключением гаммы. Гамма должна получится такой же, как и при шифровании. В таком случае - можно использовать одну функцию для crypt/decrypt